# Send true or false to database wether checkbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, checkbox, nedb

i got an issue regarding checkboxes with nedb. I want to send true or false if the checkbox is checked or not to the database i cannot solve this issue. i am working with node.js and nedb. please help!

client js eventlistener:

```
var taskDone = document.querySelectorAll('.taskDone');


taskDone.forEach(btn => {
     btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var done = e.target.attributes[1].value;

        let id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        let isDone = document.querySelector(`input[data-id=${id}]`).value;

        console.log(isDone + "isdone")
        if ($(taskDone).is(':checked')) {
            $('.text').addClass('line-through')
            console.log("trues")
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/done/' + id,
                type: 'PUT',
                data: { isDone }
            }).done(function (data) {
                //location.reload()
                console.log(data)
            })

        } else {
            console.log('falses')
            $('.text').removeClass('line-through')
        }
    })
})
```

update function to nedb:

```
    function taskIsDone (id, done) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.update({ _id: id }, { $set: done }, { returnUpdatedDocs: true }, (err, num, updateDocs) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(updateDocs)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

server:

```
app.put('/done/:_id', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    var id = req.params._id;
    let done = {
      title: req.body.isDone,
    }
      const updateToDo = await taskIsDone(id, done)
      console.log(updateToDo + " Todo done");
      res.json(updateToDo);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({error: error.message});
  }
})
```

html/ejs:

```
<% for ( var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="edit-container" >
        
                <input type="text" name="editTask" value="<%=row[i].title %>" data-id="<%=row[i]._id %>">

                <button name="<%= row[i]._id %>" class="edit" data-id="<%=row[i]._id %>">save edit</button>
        </div>
        
        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="isDone" class="taskDone" data-id="<%=row[i]._id %>">
                <span class="text"><%= row[i].title %></span>
                <button class="delete" name="<%= row[i]._id %>">delete</button>
        </div>
        <br>
    <% } %>
```

i could really need some help with this! thanks

Comment: `$(taskDone)` is using `querSelectorAll` method which returns a node list - array type. You are not selecting the actual checkbox you clicked on!

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well please ?

Comment: so what should i do instead? added the html @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Are you calling that update function on a checkbox `checked` or when you do a button click ?

Comment: it's a onclick function. but i get all the data consoled logged but don't manage to change the state if the task is done or not

Comment: Can you please add demo HTML where its shows the actual values and text of button ?

Comment: created: "2020721"
done: false
title: "Fix this thing with the checkboxes"
_id: "L5Y8QDyDbnGuUMze"

Comment: Just to be clear. You check the checkboxes you have and then you save edit button do update the DB ? Which button do you click on

Comment: I want to click on the checkbox to save to the db, not check the checkbox and then save

Comment: See my answer below. I have simplified your code and added some explanation as well. You can other add functionality and things you want to send via ajax - if required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220265/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-yde13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated a `minimal` example of what you are trying to do with checkbox checked state. I have added three checkboxes with same class name `.taskDone`

And i have using a `change` function not a `click` function. Every-time you `clicked` on the `checkbox` and check it will show the console log with checked and the `data-i`d of that `checkbox` as well.

To get the data-id you can simply use `.data` function of jQuery and just specify what you want after the `data-**` to get it stored value.

In addition, do not use `fat arrow` - `=>` function with jQuery. Use normal function statements so you can access you things by using `$(this)` instead of specifying each `class` or `id`

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let taskDone = document.querySelectorAll('.taskDone'); //get all the chechbox with same class .taskDone
taskDone.forEach(function(btn) { //use normal function
  btn.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id') //get the data id of checkbox
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //check if the clicked checkbox is checked or not
      console.log(id + ' is Checked - Updating neDB') //console.log
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/done/' + id,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: 'isDone'
      }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
    } else {
      console.log("Not Checked")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="isDone" class="taskDone" data-id="1">

<input type="checkbox" name="isDone" class="taskDone" data-id="2">

<input type="checkbox" name="isDone" class="taskDone" data-id="3">
```